# How to tight the Row in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, row

My `Row()`is too loose. I'd like it to stick to the child.

I tried to add a Flexible with a FlexibleFit.tight with no success.

```dart
  return Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10, horizontal: 20),
            child: Column(children: [
              ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  child:
                      // === The logo
                      Container(
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(border: Border.all()),
                          child: Flexible(
                              fit: FlexFit.tight,
                              child: Row(
                                  
                                  children: [
                                    StringBadge()
                                    StringBadge()
                                    StringBadge()
                                  ])
                                  // etc.
```

[image]

Comment: can you include StringBadge?

Comment: `StringBadge` is a custom widget (with many lines of code) that does not add to the question. You could think of it as a simple `Text('Hello')`.

Comment: The question is a bit unclear (`like it to stick to the child`), but if you want the parent widget `Row()` to wrap its children tightly then the correct solution is the one you posted here -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/74783762/3002719.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally added a `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` as follows:

```dart
Row(
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // <= HERE
    children: [
        StringBadge(),
        StringBadge(),
        StringBadge(),
```

Answer (score 1):

Just wrap each of the children of ROW with Expanded

```html
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(child: StringBadge()),
                                    Expanded(child: StringBadge()),
                                    Expanded(child: StringBadge()),
                                  ])
```

Answer (score 0):

you must use Expanded Widget. this widget help to keep all screen.

for Example:

```
Row(
     children: 
      [
      Expanded(child: StringBadge()),
      Expanded(child: StringBadge()),
      Expanded(child: StringBadge()),
                                  ]
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how your UI should look like, there are few options:

0. like the others said, wrap each child in an expanded. however, there may be other implications for this depending on the child widget.
1. use the `mainAxisAlignment` property of the Row widget

```dart
Row(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spacedBetween, // or spacedEvenly, etc
  children: [
    StringBadge(),
    ...,
    StringBadge(),
  ],
),
```

2. Use `Spacer()` to put an expanding space between the widgets

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    StringBadge(),
    const Spacer(), // place it/them wherever necessary
    StringBadge(),
    StringBadge(),
  ],
),
```